# pcs creating cluster fails because of unknown hosts

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, pacemaker, ubuntu-20.04, corosync

I am following several tutorials now and all of them have such steps -- authenticate given hosts in pcs and then create cluster. Yet in my case the first step (authenticating) works while the second does not with error stating the hosts are not known/authenticated.

```sh
sudo pcs host auth 192.168.4.201 192.168.4.202
```

and then

```sh
sudo pcs cluster setup my_cluster 192.168.4.201 192.168.4.202
```

And for this I get this peculiar error:

> Warning: Unable to read the known-hosts file: No such file or directory: '/var/lib/pcsd/known-hosts'
> Error: Hosts '192.168.4.201', '192.168.4.202' are not known to pcs, try to authenticate the hosts using 'pcs host auth 192.168.4.201 192.168.4.202' command
> Error: None of hosts is known to pcs.

The recommended step (in error message) is exactly what I did. What is missing here for real?

*Ubuntu 20.04.2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague looked at it and suggested to check the status of the pcs. It appeared that some node was already running (probably just installing packages creates some default cluster), so we destroyed everything (`pcs cluster destroy`), started pcsd again and then repeated the steps.

It worked this time.

*I hope it was a good move.*

Comment: also faced the same issue and solved it the same way, 
only after destroying and repeating pcs auth... known_hosts file was created